# Show by direct proof that if $g \circ f$ is one-to-one, $f$ is one-to-one

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

$f: A \to B$ and $g: B\to C$ are maps (this is part of the question).

Here's my idea:

Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x,y \in A$. Then $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$, as $g \circ f$ is one-to-one. We can rewrite this as $(g \circ f)(x) = (g \circ f)(y)$. Since we know $g \circ f$ is injective, then $x$ must equal $y$. QED.

Is this close? What errors am I making?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all looks correct except for one thing:

> Then $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$, as $g \circ f$ is one-to-one.

This isn't because $g \circ f$ is one-to-one. This is because if $f(x)=f(y)$, then we can substitute $f(x)$ for $f(y)$ in any expression and vice versa. In particular, if we plug it into $g$, we have $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$. The only place you need to use injectivity of $g\circ f$ is when you finally conclude $x=y$.

Comment: But the thing that worries me is, how do we know that plugging a value into g always yields the same answer? It was never defined that g was one-to-one.

Comment: So how do we know that $g(z)=g(z)$? That's a mystery.... @o's1234

Comment: Is that something that we can take as a given? I'm sorry, I feel like I sometimes overcomplicate problems.

Comment: Yep, part of the definition of a function is that every input $x$ has one and only one output $f(x)$. So in particular, if $x=y$, then $f(x)=f(y)$. In some sense it seems obvious to some, but it becomes important to think about later when you may have different representations of elements in your domain (e.g. functions on a set of equivalence classes)

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote your responses but I don't have enough reputation to...